# unable to get index of date in array with apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

using apps script, I try to get the index of the top of column date within an array of month / year values. The code triggers on editing any cell below those date columns.

Index keeps returning -1 instead of the index position in the array.

What am I doing wrong ??

Link to the spreadsheet :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/121HEP0EDRcGsxX72n_ga6-_pAgLnlAGWukGc5WmXdfo/edit?usp=sharing

Here's the code :

```
function onEdit(e) {
  testIndexOf(e)
}

function testIndexOf(e) {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let month = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];
  let months = ss.getRange('A2:A14').getDisplayValues() // 2D array
  let months1D = months.map(function(r) { return r[0] }) // 1D array
    
  let sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  //let currentDate = sheet.getRange(1, e.range.columnStart).getValue()
  let currentDate = sheet.getRange(1, e.range.columnStart).getDisplayValue()
  let currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear()
  let currentMonth = month[currentDate.getMonth() ]
  let monthYear = currentMonth + " " + currentYear 

  // get index of month/year in column A
  let index = months1D.indexOf(monthYear)
  Logger.log("monthYear : " + monthYear + "\n")
  Logger.log("index : " + index)
}
```

When using .getDisplayValue() :

LOG :

Jan 31, 2022, 10:53:12 AM
Error
TypeError: currentDate.getFullYear is not a function
at testIndexOf(Code:14:33)
at onEdit(Code:2:3)

Comment: Use `.getDisplayValues()` instead of `.getValues()`

Comment: I tried it (for the "months" array) : still get -1

Comment: [Edit] your question to show latest updated script and logs. `console.log({months,monthYear})`

Comment: Edited;  
commented the previous version

Comment: You have to use `getValue()` for `currentDate`. If you need `Date` type, use `getValue()`. If you need `String` type, use `getDisplayValue()`. Also provide `console.log({months,monthYear})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, the values of "A2:A14" has `A0` as the space. On the other hand, you are using `20` as the space at `let monthYear = currentMonth + " " + currentYear`. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue of `Index keeps returning -1 instead of the index position in the array.`. In order to return the index from the array of `month` using `monthYear`, how about the following modification?

#### Pattern 1:

When you want to use the current values of "A2:A14", please modify your script as follows.

##### From:

```
let monthYear = currentMonth + " " + currentYear
```

##### To:

```
let monthYear = currentMonth + String.fromCharCode(0xA0) + currentYear;
```

Or,

##### From:

```
let months1D = months.map(function(r) { return r[0] })
```

##### To:

```
let months1D = months.map(function (r) { return r[0].replace(String.fromCharCode(0xA0), " ") });
```

And also, please modify `let currentDate = sheet.getRange(1, e.range.columnStart).getDisplayValue()` to `let currentDate = sheet.getRange(1, e.range.columnStart).getValue()`.

#### Pattern 2:

When you want to modify the values of "A2:A14", please modify the space from `A0` to `20` (Normal space.). In this case, you are not required to modify `let monthYear = currentMonth + " " + currentYear`. In this case, you can do this using the following simple script.

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A2:A14").createTextFinder(String.fromCharCode(0xA0)).replaceAllWith(" ");
```

And also, please modify `let currentDate = sheet.getRange(1, e.range.columnStart).getDisplayValue()` to `let currentDate = sheet.getRange(1, e.range.columnStart).getValue()`.

Comment: Wow, I never would have find that by myself !
First time I hear about that bizarre quirk.

Thank you very much for going at great length with your detailed explanation !

Comment: @Michel Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.