# apps script : why can I not split this 2 words string?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a dropdown list with month and year in cell A4 (January 2022, February 2022,...)
The script reads it correctly as a string but doesn't do the actual split.
I tried to read getValue or getDisplayValue().

It returns a string but doens't want to split it.

```
function splitMonthYear() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Filter Dates");
  
  let dateFilter = sheet.getRange("A4").getValue()
   
  Logger.log("dateFilter : "   + dateFilter + " typeof : " + typeof(dateFilter)  + " - " + dateFilter.length)
  
  String(dateFilter).split(" ")
  Logger.log("dateFilter 2 : "   + dateFilter + " typeof : " + typeof(dateFilter)  + " - " + dateFilter.length)
  Logger.log("dateFilter[0]: "   + dateFilter[0] + " typeof : " + typeof(dateFilter[0])  )
  
  let monthFilter = dateFilter[0];
  let yearFilter = dateFilter[1] 
  Logger.log("monthFilter : "   + monthFilter + " - yearFilter : " + yearFilter)
}
```

link to spreadsheet :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cE4FRKeVb8EMqm4q9brpjTcLPpZBH4qXud99lto--WQ/edit#gid=1192683053

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your script, by `String(dateFilter).split(" ")`, `dateFilter` is not changed. Please assign the result of it to a variable.
- When I saw your script, situation, and your sample Spreadsheet, I thought that your issue might be related to your question. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70918960/7108653) Namely, your single space might be `A0` instead of `20`.

I thought that the above 2 points might be the reason for your issue. When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
String(dateFilter).split(" ")
```

#### To:

```
dateFilter = String(dateFilter).split(String.fromCharCode(0xA0));
```

- If your single space is `20` which is not `A0`, please modify to `dateFilter = String(dateFilter).split(" ");`

#### Reference:

- [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Thanks ! That was it again ! I tried to implement your solution, but failed badly.
Thanks again for your help !

Comment: @Michel Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
function splitMonthYear() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  let dv = sheet.getRange("A4").getDisplayValue().split(",");
  dv.pop();
  let a = dv.map(e => e.trim())
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(a));
}

Execution log
5:21:56 PM  Notice  Execution started
5:21:56 PM  Info    ["January 2022","February 2022"]
5:21:57 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: sorry, I probably stated the problem imprecisely ; the goal was to split the month and year from the selected value in the dropdown list.